# Refrigerating leftover cooked potato

Tags: potatoes, refrigerator

My mom keeps telling me it is unsafe to refrigerate leftover cooked potato in any form because she claims refrigeration accumulates toxins in them (or something like that).  I, on the other hand, often refrigerate all forms of cooked potato, including but not limited to boiled, roasted, meshed etc.  Often, I will boil a bunch of potatoes, refrigerate them and then just slightly sautee them with spices before eating.

Who is right?  Can it be bad to eat leftover refrigerated potatoes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refrigerating cooked potatoes is perfectly safe.  The myriad of frozen and refrigerated potato products on the market demonstrate this, as do the experiences of millions of home cooks.

In fact, it is raw potatoes that should not be refrigerated, not because of safety concerns, but because they will convert starches to sugars and taste oddly sweet.  The ideal storage temperature is slightly higher, 45-50 F.

Comment: Potato salad is a prime example of refrigerated cooked potates.